# Mod Rewrite with question mark in result

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs that look like mysite.com/go/somevalue and I want to redirect them to mysite.com?shorturl=somevalue. Think of it as a branded url shortener.

I have tried the following among other incarnations. I think the problem is with the question mark in the results.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /go(.*) %3F$1
RedirectMatch 301 /go(.*) \?$1
RewriteRule ^.*/go/(.*)$ \?shorturl=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `RedirectMatch` should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/go/(.+)$ /?$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to escape the `?` if you want tha tas part of the query string:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/go/(.*)$ ?shorturl=$1
```

The other two statements are mod_alias redirects, which will redirect the browser and cause the location bar to change. If that's what you want, you can add a `[L,R=301]` to the end of the rewrite rule and not have a need for the `RedirectMatch` lines